# C# Dev Express Ribbon Form - Design-Time: System Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, devexpress, ribbon-form

#### .......

I keep getting that nasty out of memory exception, for which I plan to blame Dev Express completely. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong to make this happen?
I've got a Ribbon Form (Which takes ages to load up in Design view when I want to play with the controls on the form........But I'm guessing thats just the nature of the thing.

#### Help greatly appreciated.

#### EDIT

When I double-click on my form in Visual Studio, instead of it displaying the form it displays this HUGE ERROR MESSAGE.

Comment: If you want help, you have to give some details... From the question I'm not even sure if you get the error runtime or design-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The workaround I found is to close all design views and rebuild the project. Following these, I could open the form in design view.